# Android.OS.FileUriExposedException when trying to open a file in MAUI Android app

Tags: c#, android, file, android-intent, maui

I am working on a MAUI Android app where I need to open a file located in the Downloads directory. I have written code to construct the file path and open it using the Launcher.Default.OpenAsync method as per the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?tabs=android).

```
  #if ANDROID
    string dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;
  #else
    string dir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Downloads");
  #endif
    string folderName = rework.ServiceOrder.ServiceOrderNo;
    string folderPath = Path.Combine(dir, folderName);
  // Created directory and added files I can see the folder in the Files
    var uri = new Uri(folderPath).AbsoluteUri;
    await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync(uri);
```

However, I am getting the following **exception**:

> Android.OS.FileUriExposedException:
> file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/TN1910013 exposed beyond app
> through Intent.getData()

I have already tried adding the necessary intent filter in the AndroidManifest.xml file, as mentioned in the documentation. Here is the relevant portion of my manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="maui_app" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This code works perfectly on Windows and opens the file explorer with the correct directory. However, it does not work on my Android local device. How can I resolve this issue and successfully open the file in my MAUI Android app?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Already since Android 7/N you cannot use file uries. Google a bit and plenty of answers.

Comment: tried this await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync(folderPath);
Got this exception: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Download/TN1910013 flg=0x14000000 }

Comment: i am able to open one file from the directory from below code but i want to open the directory
 //string popoverTitle =folderName;
                //await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest(popoverTitle, new ReadOnlyFile(filepath)));

Comment: You clearly did not google otherwise you had used FileProvider.